# Expand angular material accordion

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have 2 different accordion in same page. each accordion has multiple expansion panel. how to close all the expanded panel from 2 accordions and open currently selected expansion panel?? i can able to close current accordion's expansion panel but other one remains open. and two accordion does the same except it fetches data from different list and some div comes between two accordion

```
`<mat-accordion [multi]= "true"  >
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor = "let item of items" (click) = "viewItem(item)" >
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
           <mat-panel-title>
              //something
           </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            //something..
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion> 
<mat-accordion [multi]= "true"  >
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor = "let item of items" (click) = "viewItem(item)" >
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
         <mat-panel-title>
              //something
         </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            //something..
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can close all other panels when you open one of them:

TS

```
@ViewChildren(MatExpansionPanel) panels: QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>;

closeOtherPanels(openPanel: MatExpansionPanel) {
    this.panels.forEach(panel => {
        if (panel !== openPanel) {
            panel.close();
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<mat-accordion [multi]= "true">
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor = "let item of items" (click) = "viewItem(item)" #panel (opened)="closeOtherPanels(panel)" >
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
           <mat-panel-title>
              //something
           </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            //something..
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion> 
<mat-accordion [multi]= "true">
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor = "let item of items" (click) = "viewItem(item)" #panel (opened)="closeOtherPanels(panel)" >
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
         <mat-panel-title>
              //something
         </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            //something..
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: Works pretty well! Would have been great to have this as native functionality.